# Click on a cell in DTdatatable and move to another tab of a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny dashboard below and I would like to know if I could make the cells of the column `Species` interactive in a way that if the user clicks on a word of that column ,for example `'setosa'`, to move to the tab `Species`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Documents",
                 DTOutput("dt1")),
        tabPanel("Species")
      )
    ),

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    library(readxl)

    output$dt1<-renderDT(
      iris,filter = "top",
      options = list(
        pageLength = 5
      )
    )

  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(tabsetPanel(
      id = "myTabsetPanel",
      tabPanel("Documents",
               DTOutput("dt1")),
      tabPanel("Species")
    )),

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt1 <- renderDT(
      iris,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )

    observeEvent(input$dt1_cell_clicked, {
      # alternative: input$dt1_cells_selected
      if (req(input$dt1_cell_clicked$value) == "setosa") {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "myTabsetPanel", selected = "Species")
      }
    })

  }
)
```

Comment: Based on your approach could you take a look at this? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911536/display-datatable-based-on-certain-cell-selection-of-another-datatable-and-in-ac

Comment: You could probably help with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958925/hide-a-tab-in-shiny-app-when-the-user-is-not-in-this-tab-or-deactivate-it