# Display datatable based on certain cell selection of another datatable and in active tab in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny dashboard below in which in tab `Documents` I display the first 2 lines of the `iris` dataset.

When I click on any cell of the column `Species` I automatically move to the `View` tab.

But  I need the functionality described below.

When the user clicks on the `setosa` cell of the 1st row in `Documents` tab the datatable in the sidebar in the `View` tab only should display `iris` dataset. When I click on the `setosa` cell of the  the 2nd row in `Documents` tab the datatable in the sidebar in the `View` tab only should display another dataframe, lets say `mtcars`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
      DT::DTOutput("dt2")
    ),
    body = dashboardBody(tabsetPanel(
      id = "myTabsetPanel",
      tabPanel("Documents",
               DTOutput("dt1")),
      tabPanel("Species")
    )),

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt1 <- renderDT(
      iris[1:2,],
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )

    observeEvent(input$dt1_cell_clicked, {
      # alternative: input$dt1_cells_selected
      if (req(input$dt1_cell_clicked$value) == "setosa") {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "myTabsetPanel", selected = "Species")
      }
    })
    output$dt2<-renderDT(
      if(input$myTabsetPanel=="Species"){
        iris
      }
      else{
        return(NULL)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(datasets)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(tabsetPanel(
      id = "myTabsetPanel",
      tabPanel("Documents",
               DT::DTOutput("dt1")),
      tabPanel("Species",
               DT::DTOutput("dt2"))
    )),

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt1 <- renderDT(
      iris[1:2,],
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )

    observeEvent(input$dt1_cell_clicked, {
      # alternative: input$dt1_cells_selected
      if (req(input$dt1_cell_clicked$value) == "setosa") {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "myTabsetPanel", selected = "Species")
      }
    })

    output$dt2 <- renderDT(
      if(input$dt1_cell_clicked$row == 1){
        iris
      }
      else{
        mtcars
      }
    )
  }
)
```