# Hide a tab in shiny app when the user is not in this tab. Or deactivate it

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have the shiny dashboard below and I have made the cells of the column `Species` interactive in a way that if the user clicks on a word of that column ,for example 'setosa', to move to the tab `Species`.This is the only way someone can move to this tab. The issue  is that I do not want the tab `Species` to be displayed when the user is not in this tab. A secondary solution would be to deactivate `Species` 'click on' ability. So if the user would accidentaly press it nothing would happen.

```
    library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(tabsetPanel(
      id = "myTabsetPanel",
      tabPanel("Documents",
               DTOutput("dt1")),
      tabPanel("Species",
               DTOutput("dt2"))
    )),

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt1 <- renderDT(
      iris,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )
    output$dt2 <- renderDT(
      mtcars,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )
    observeEvent(input$dt1_cell_clicked, {
      # alternative: input$dt1_cells_selected
      if (req(input$dt1_cell_clicked$value) == "setosa") {
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "myTabsetPanel", selected = "Species")
      }
    })

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** observe the `input$dt1_cells_selected` and reset the value at the end of the `observeEvent` to allow same cell selection to re-trigger the tab open. You will need to use a `dataTableProxy` to do this.

You can use `hideTab` and `showTab` to reactively hide and show the tab, but still be able to navigate to it via a data table click. [More info here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/showTab.html). I added a table output to the "Species" tab so we can tell if it has switched properly. By adding an observeEvent around the `input$myTabsetPanel` we can have the "Species" tab hidden whenever `input$myTabsetPanel` == Documents:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(tabsetPanel(
      id = "myTabsetPanel",
      tabPanel("Documents",
               DTOutput("dt1")),

      tabPanel("Species",
               DTOutput("dt2"))
    ))

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$myTabsetPanel, {
      if(input$myTabsetPanel == "Documents"){
        hideTab("myTabsetPanel", "Species")
      }
    })

    output$dt1 <- renderDT(
      iris,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )

    output$dt2 <- renderDT(
      mtcars,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(pageLength = 5),
      selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
    )



    myProxy = DT::dataTableProxy('dt1')


    observeEvent(input$dt1_cells_selected,{
      # alternative: input$dt1_cells_selected
      if (req(input$dt1_cell_clicked$value) == "setosa") {
        showTab("myTabsetPanel", "Species")
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "myTabsetPanel", selected = "Species")
        DT::selectCells(myProxy, NULL)
      }
    })


  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: But now its like the Species does not exist at all. I cannot see the table that is supposed be in there.

Comment: Updated to fix this

Comment: I noticed that when I click on setosa , I move to the 2nd tab but if I click on the same setosa again immediatelly it does nothing.

Comment: thats based on your logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012913/if-statement-does-not-work-2-times-in-a-row-in-a-shiny-app

Comment: Ah, interesting. I think it is coming from the observeEvent. Clicking the same row, column 'setosa' does not update that reactive value so it is not re-triggering