# If statement does not work 2 times in a row in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app which displays 3 tabs.

In the `Documents` tab there is a table. When the user clicks on the `setosa` of the 1st row he is moving to the `View` tab (visible only when click happens) and sees a table. When the user clicks on the `setosa` of the 2nd row he is moving to the `View` tab and sees another table. Also those tables must be visible only on `View` tab.

The app seems to work fine but if I click on the 1st row `setosa` ,move to the `View` tab, return to the `Documents` tab again and try to click again the 1st row `setosa` nothing happens. I have to click the 2nd row `setosa` to make it work again. The same happens with the 2nd row `setosa`.

In a few words I cannot do the same action twice in a row and I feel that my `if` condition is responsible for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(
    header = dashboardHeaderPlus(title = span(strong("ArmorDoc"),style = "color: black;")

    ),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(

    ),
    body = dashboardBody(

      useShinyjs(),
      tags$hr(),
      tabsetPanel(
        id ="tabA",
        type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Documents",icon = icon("accusoft"),
                 tags$hr(),
                 DTOutput("dt1")),
        tabPanel("View", icon = icon("table"),
                 DTOutput("dt3")
        ),
        tabPanel("Upload", icon = icon("table")

        )

      )

    )),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$tabA, {
      if(input$tabA == "Documents"|input$tabA=="Upload"){
        hideTab("tabA", "View")
      }
    })



    observeEvent(input$dt1_cell_clicked, {
      # alternative: input$dt1_cells_selected
      if (req(input$dt1_cell_clicked$value) == "setosa") {
        showTab("tabA", "View")
        updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "tabA", selected = "View")
      }
    })

    output$dt1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        iris[1:2,],
        filter = "top",
        options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, search = list(search = ""),pageLength = 5,columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = "_all"))),rownames= FALSE,
        selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'cell')
      ) 

    })


    output$dt3 <- renderDT(server = F,
                           if(input$dt1_cell_clicked$row == 1&input$tabA=="View"){

                             datatable(iris)
                           }
                           else if(input$dt1_cell_clicked$row == 2&input$tabA=="View"){
                             datatable(mtcars)
                           }
                           else{
                             return(NULL)
                           }
    )


  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61958925/hide-a-tab-in-shiny-app-when-the-user-is-not-in-this-tab-or-deactivate-it). Its the same `Proxy` method in the `observeEvent()`.